# Populating UITableView from JSON

Tags: swift4, xcode9

I'm trying to use a JSON file to populate a UITableView in my app. Previously I was hard coding an array of sample data, but need to move to using my JSON file. This is a mishmash of various tutorials and answers found on SO, so I apologize if the syntax conventions are a little off.

```
import UIKit
import os.log

class BonusTableViewController: UITableViewController {

    //MARK: Properties
    var bonuses = [Bonus]() // Used for old sample data
    var jBonuses = [Bonuses]() // Used with JSON based data

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    //MARK: Confirm JSON file was loaded and log the Bonus Codes
        let loadedBonuses = loadJson(filename: "BonusData")
        for bonus in loadedBonuses! {
            print(bonus.bonusCode)
        }
    }

    // Load the JSON file from the bundled file.
    func loadJson(filename fileName: String) -> [Bonuses]? {
        if let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: fileName, withExtension: "json") {
            do {
                let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
                let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                let jsonData = try decoder.decode(JSONData.self, from: data)
                print("loadJson loaded JSON")
                return jsonData.bonuses
            } catch {
                print("error:\(error)")
            }
        }
        return nil
    }

    // MARK: Data Structures
    // Bonus Data Structs
    struct JSONData: Decodable {
        let name: String
        let version: String
        let bonuses: [Bonuses]
    }
    struct Bonuses: Decodable {
        let bonusCode: String
        let category: String
        let name: String
        let value: Int
        let city: String
        let state: String
        let flavor: String
        let imageData: String
    }

    // MARK: - Table view data source
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return jBonuses.count
    }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        // Table view cells are reused and should be dequeued using a cell identifier.
        let cellIdentifier = "BonusTableViewCell"

        guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as? BonusTableViewCell else {
            fatalError("The dequeued cell is not an instance of BonusTableViewCell.")
        }
    // Now using JSON file
        let jBonus = jBonuses[indexPath.row]
        print("Setting labels using JSON file")
        cell.bonusCodeLabel.text = jBonus.bonusCode
        cell.categoryLabel.text = jBonus.category
        cell.nameLabel.text = jBonus.name
        cell.valueLabel.text = "\(jBonus.value)"
        cell.cityLabel.text = "\(jBonus.city),"
        cell.stateLabel.text = jBonus.state
        cell.flavorText.text = jBonus.flavor
        cell.primaryImage.image = jBonus.photo

        return cell
    }
```

From the console, I can confirm that it is able to see the JSON data and it does spit out the list of bonus codes. I can't pinpoint why this isn't working, but the result is a blank just a tableview with a bunch of empty rows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace `viewDidLoad` with

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    jBonuses = loadJson(filename: "BonusData")!
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

You have to assign the loaded data to the data source array and reload the table view.

Or if `loadedBonuses` could really be `nil` (it cannot in this case):

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    if let loadedBonuses = loadJson(filename: "BonusData") {
        jBonuses = loadedBonuses
        tableView.reloadData()
    }
}
```

Notes:

- Delete the method `numberOfSections`, `1` is the default.
- Force unwrap the cell, the code must not crash if everything is hooked up properly

  ```
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellIdentifier, for: indexPath) as! BonusTableViewCell
  ```

Answer (score 0):

You are populating Tableview using jBonuses array of Type Bonuses, but where you are filling the jBonuses array.

It seems that you are not filling jBonuses Array. Fill the jBonuses array once you get API response and call tableview reloadData method.

```
yourTableView.reloadData()
```